Having path problem while downloading the synthesize audio file
This is my downloader provider class code
 Future<void> downloadFile(String text, String filename) async {
    // Check for permission to access storage
    if (!await _checkPermission()) {
      print("Permission not granted.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Get the download directory
      var downloadDirectory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      if (downloadDirectory == null) {
        print("Download directory not found.");
        return;
      }
      print('Download directory path: ${downloadDirectory.path}');

      // Construct the file path
      String filePath = "${downloadDirectory.path}/$filename";

      // Synthesize text to audio file
      await flutterTts.synthesizeToFile(
        text,
        filePath,
        // Provide optional parameters like audioFormat, quality, etc. if needed
      );

      // Check if the file was created successfully
      File audioFile = File(filePath);
      if (!await audioFile.exists()) {
        print("Audio file not found.");
        return;
      }

      // Set the downloaded file path
      _downloadedFile = filePath;
      print('Downloaded file: $_downloadedFile');

      updateDownloadStatus(DownloadStatus.Completed);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error synthesizing or downloading file: $e');
      updateDownloadStatus(DownloadStatus.NotStarted);
    }
  }

And this is where am implementing my above mentioned code
 Widget dowloadButton(FileDownloaderProvider downloaderProvider) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        var downloadDirectory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
        if (downloadDirectory == null) {
          print("Download directory not found.");
          return;
        }

        String filePath = "${downloadDirectory.path}/myFile.mp3";
        downloaderProvider.downloadFile(widget.text, filePath).then((onValue) {
          // Handle the completion of the download if needed
        });
      },
      child: const Text(
        "Download File",
      ),
    );
  }

but its giving me the error that
/TTS     (18244): Failed creating file : /storage/emulated/0/Download/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.text_to_speech/files/downloads/myFile.mp3
I/flutter (18244): Audio file not found.

i dont know why i have tried everything anyone please help me!
Am trying to download the flutter tts synthesize file of audio in my mobile download directory
